# Suppress system broadcasts/messages

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to suppress messages in vim that are coming from the system or shell? E.g. message from sysadmin or batch queue messages when jobs complete.

**Note that I want to specify this at the vim command line or in .vimrc, NOT at the shell or system level.** I am using an obscure operating system (OpenVMS) so answers specific to Windows, Linux, or MacOS will unfortunately not be helpful to me.

The rationale, if it matters: I'll often have a large number of batch jobs complete which writes over my text in vim and I have to repeatedly hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the screen. I don't want to turn off the messages at the system or shell level because I want to see them. I just don't want them messing up my text in vim.

In a different editor the system messages would display at the bottom of the window without screwing up the text so if anyone knows how to make vim do that, I would also consider accepting that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me based on the comments of @Carpetsmoker and @Mass (thanks to both!)

Added these lines to `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter * silent ! set broadcast=none
autocmd VimLeave * silent ! set broadcast=all
```

This simply turns messages off when you start vim, and then turns them back on when you exit vim.  `set broadcast=xxx` is specific to OpenVMS but I imagine this would work for linux/windows/mac if you substituted the appropriate command.

Comment: For completeness, you're saying `autocmd VimEnter * silent !set broadcast=none` produced a "Press ENTER" message?

Comment: Ah, okay.  FYI: `silent` must precede each command it is to make silent, by itself it does nothing.  So, `autocmd VimEnter * silent !set broadcast=none` may have worked, but putting `silent` on a separate line will definitely not work, as expected.

Comment: @Mass  Thanks!  You are exactly correct about that.  I have edited it to reflect that.  I initially misunderstood what you were saying.